Flutter Dart Package Privacy Manifest Requirement
Following Apple's announcement regarding the requirement of having a Privacy Manifest from the beginning of May, I have failed to find any information about what steps a pure Dart package needs to perform in order to comply to it.
Since Flutter has been listed under the "commonly used sdks", do I just need to upgrade my Dart package to depend on Flutter 3.19.0 (which added privacy manifest support)?
Or do I need to include a privacy manifest file (most probably empty) to my Dart package?
For a Plugin package, which has native code, there are steps one can take in order to be compatible with the guidelines, but that is due to the presence of classes and folders which are relevant for iOS.
These though, do not exist for a pure Dart package.

If you are talking about a pure Dart package then you don't have to do anything. The needed Privacy Manifest will be provided by the Flutter app project that uses your package

Not even enforcing the minimum version of Flutter to be 3.16? Since that added a privacy manifest for Flutter.

nope, a dart package knows nothing about ios or android.

But when you create a dart package, there are android and ios folders.

Only if you create the package with the Flutter create command. See my get_it repository. https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it
